# Import CSV table and skip first column from mysql table

Tags: mysql, linux, csv

I got one table like this:

```
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| my_id      | int(5)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| col1       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| col2       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| col3       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

and I want to import a CSV file into this table. Problem is that in CSV I don't have my_id column, so I need to insert data beginning from 2nd column (col1) as the first must be and kind of count of each row.

Edit: I just did the basic import and mysql "removed" my first column from CSV:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/home/bruno/myfield.csv"
INTO TABLE teste
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ESCAPED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

When I import I got:

```
| my_id      | col2                 | col3             | col4            |
+------------+----------------------+------------------+-----------------+
|          1 | lorem ipsum          | SER1             | testingmyfield4 |
|          2 | dolor emet           | SER1             | testingmyfield4 |
```

Comment: since my_id is auto increment I dont think you should face any issue on doing so. Have you tried anything and having any problem?

Comment: I improved with the result @apomene, my col1 is being subscribed by the auto increment.
So I wanted to be in my column autoincrement+csv(col1, col2... coln)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sql query to get the columns and save it in file like the query below

> SELECT col1,col2,..  FROM `tablename` INTO OUTFILE 
>    'location where u want to save the file'

or you can the try the tools which will be available in internet like mysqlyog,mysqlworkbench

Hope you find this answer helpfull

Comment: Hi shaan, in my case the table is empty, I'm trying to import CSV to it.